# angular4 angular2 - XSRF protection

Tags: angular, csrf

We are currently working on an Angular4 app with Slim-PHP REST Backend. Now we want to implement XSRF protection. Is it correct that there is no official tutorial on Angular2 or Angular4, how to use the classes `XSRFStrategy`, `CookieXSRFStrategy`, etc. on the client side? (We put an XSRF TOKEN cookie on the server side and wont that angular send a XSRF TOKEN-header-parameter).

We have found many threads in forums, however, all with individual cases ... On the page "https://angular.io/guide/security" there is also no detailed information on how to use it. Or did I miss something? Does anyone have a tip?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url that you provided has a link to the class [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection), where you can find the following text:

> Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF) is an attack technique by which the
>   attacker can trick an authenticated user into unknowingly executing
>   actions on your website. HttpClient supports a common mechanism used
>   to prevent XSRF attacks. When performing HTTP requests, an interceptor
>   reads a token from a cookie, by default XSRF-TOKEN, and sets it as an
>   HTTP header, X-XSRF-TOKEN. Since only code that runs on your domain
>   could read the cookie, the backend can be certain that the HTTP
>   request came from your client application and not an attacker.

This is configurable:

> If your backend service uses different names for the XSRF token cookie
>   or header, use `HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions()` to override the
>   defaults.
>
> ```
>  imports: [   HttpClientModule,  
>    HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
>      cookieName: 'My-Xsrf-Cookie',
>      headerName: 'My-Xsrf-Header'
>    }) ]
> ```

Comment: Please, if this answer helped you, select it as accept in order to mark the question as answered ;)

Comment: I'll do that, of course. I still had problems with setting the cookie via PHP. Apparently, Angular accept only XSRF-TOKEN-Cookies which have a expire and domain value.

My first try:
`setcookie('XSRF-TOKEN', $value);`
Angular ignored the cookie and did not set any parameters in header.

Then I specified the expire time and domain.
`setcookie('XSRF-TOKEN', $value, time() + (86400 * 1), "/");`

Angular has read the cookie and set the X-XSRF-TOKEN header parameter correctly.

Perhaps that helps someone.

Comment: For some reasons, my Angular front-end is not sending the X-XSRF-TOKEN header. I can see the XSRF-TOKEN in the response cookies.  I thought Angular will then attach the X-XSRF-TOKEN header to every outgoing mutating requests (e.g. POST, PUT ...). 

Am I mising anything here?

Comment: @gye did find out why?

Comment: @dCrux No, I haven't figured out why. Can you provide some insights, please?

Comment: @gye yea i figured something out today: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/17281 if you are using absolute url it won't add it

Comment: @dCrux Thank you for the share. I will look into this, and let you know what I can get. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

This should be `withOptions` not `withConfig`. I.e.: like so

```
HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
  cookieName: 'My-Xsrf-Cookie',
  headerName: 'My-Xsrf-Header'
}),
```